# clone an object from the ancestor

Tags: javascript, clone

In Javascript (ES6), I defined a tree of inherited classes :

```
class A {
  constructor () {
    (...)
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor () {
    (...)
    super();
  }
}

class C extends B {
  constructor () {
    (...)
    super();
  }
}
```

And so on (a class D extends B too, etc).

Now, in `A`, I want to write a function `resolve` that clone the current object and change only some of its fields.

```
class A {
  (...)
  resolve() {
    // I want to clone this
    const newClass = ???
  }
}
```

Is it possible to get the nested inherited constructor from A?
For instance, if I'm a `C`, is it possible to create a new `C` from `resolve`?

Otherwise, is it possible to clone `this` with all the functions are properties defined in the inherited classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `this.constructor`:

```js
class A {
  foo() { return new (this.constructor) }
}

class B extends A {
  jj() { console.log('jj') }
}

(new B).foo().jj()
```

Comment: Hooo, it can't be so easy! Thanks, you made my day :)